# GFCI red LED fault indicator circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Just kindly share what kind of input in the violet dot at center to inject so the red fault led would turn on?

When the GFCI no longer function, the red led lights up. I'd like to understand how the circuit detects it. Please focus on the one in blue. The one in red is the electronic reset button. The one in black is the original circuit in the datasheet. It is the same chip as the Fairchild RV4141A popularly used. http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/81/73/817329/rv4141a.pdf

[image: reverse-engineered schematic]

See full circuit diagram at https://imageshack.com/a/img923/6796/7i3hHP.jpg

Here are the two solenoids. One to open contacts, one to close contacts, in the USA, the closing of contacts or Reset is mechanical hence no second solenoid.

[image: 3]

When you remove the main diode, the red LED lights up. What kind of circuit in the blue section can do that?

(I have another open question, [asking for help identifying unknown diodes and an SCR/transistor(?)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417739/identification-question-tiny-scr-colorful-zener) shown in that schematic, so I can't mark their types on the schematic yet.)

Comment: Hi, Some parts of *this* question duplicate parts of your *previous* question from 4 hours ago: "[Identification question - tiny SCR & colorful Zener?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/417739)". Personally I think you aren't waiting long enough between your various GFCI reverse-engineering questions, and this is an example of what can happen i.e. overlap of the topics. This could lead to your questions being closed and/or downvoted due to the duplication between them. I suggest you link to that question, and remove the duplicate identification questions (last paragraph) from this one.

Comment: I removed the last paragraph, how do I link this to the other post? Kindly help me link it. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've edited your question to add a link to the previous question, and add some explanation. I still think that you asking *this* question is premature. I would wait until you have an *accurate* reverse-engineered schematic (i.e. after the components have been identified, or until it becomes clear that they can't be identified - and then you would have to carry out further tests) before asking for help to understand the design. At the moment, you could waste people's time, trying to interpret the incomplete schematic... But at least the duplicate identification questions have been removed.

Comment: Without giving the full schematic above. They may not be identified or.their functions know as some commenter commented there. Hence im sharing full schematic etc. If i added all above to the other post. Its too much addition and cant jive with some answers there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand everything you just said, but I'm stopping now, so just briefly: "*im sharing full schematic*" What you've linked isn't what *I* would call a "full schematic" e.g. some component types / values are unknown, as evidenced by your other question, and some connections are unclear (e.g. only one connection shown to solenoids, which must actually have 2 connections) etc. etc. This is why, IMHO, it's premature to expect people to analyse the schematic *now*. "*If i added all above to the other post*" I have never suggested that you do that. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: picture edited. Note the GFCI is the only 240v gfci receptacle in the entire world with hundreds of thousands of distribution and the model will remain so for a decade more. There is no 240v gfci outlet with auto-monitoring self-test. So it has some kind poor man version of the circuit fault test. So those who know how the fault indicator red led knows, kindly share. It's not just for me but for millions of others especially in third world countries and Asia..